# Azure Machine Learning error trying to deploy a model- "Deployment failed due to timeout while waiting for Environment Image to become available"

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have registered a model and I cannot seem to get the deployment working. I always get the error "Deployment failed due to timeout while waiting for Environment Image to become available"

I tried using the default settings when using the wizard to deploy the model
[image]

I also tried different vm sizes

I also tried changing the Initial Delay value from 600 seconds to 2400 seconds.
[image]

I also tried deploying via a jupyter notebook. When I do that I get the same error but with a path to the build log. I can't see this build log when I try to find it in the storage account.
[image]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: which is the `environment` you are choosing while deployment?

Comment: It just says "Auto-generated" for the environment

Comment: I tried again using a more powerful VM but got the same error. Maybe it's possible to set up the environment first and then deploy?

Comment: @StephenAnderson I am having the exact same issue. Did you manage to get it to work as I have tried over 10 times now with varying VM sizes and counts (1, 2 and 3 instances) and no luck...

Comment: I raised a support ticket with Microsoft and, after working with them during this week, they have now confirmed it is a bug and they are working on a fix as a priority (no ETA yet).

Answer (score 0):

There is a gap in Endpoints work with Environments. The gist of it is that endpoint is awaiting for image to appear for the specified environment. If environment image is materialized within a timeout set on the endpoints side, you should be fine. If it failed or it takes longer, there is luck of clarity. Endpoints timeout for environments part is not configurable and set to 20 minutes or smth. AzureML Environment build timeout is 90 minutes for linux images. AzureML team is working on improving that experience, but there are ways to mitigate that on the user end.

Few solutions/tricks:

- Even with the endpoint failure, image build will proceed, and if no errors happen during the build it will be successfully materialized. So simple retry might solve the problem.
- You can check the environment in the UI and force a build if the error is transient: https://ml.azure.com/environments/DefaultNcdEnv-azureml-automl/version/141.
- Create you own environment, make sure the image is materialized after that reference it in the endpoint.